# Ef7 One To many relationships HasOne WithMany and Attatch

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following situation

I am attempting to save an employer with an existing address from the dbase.  I already have addresses saved and stored. I just want to save an employer with a linked address.

I thought attach would be fine and this seems to work okay when i have a new 'address' i want to save. But as soon as i try and wire up an employer to an existing address issues occur.

Things save ok - the employer and associated link to an address are saved.  But then on the next pass (save) the link is broken ( the new record takes the link ).

I am on EF7 RC1 Final.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Employers> Employers{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

public class Employer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }  
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Employer item = new Employer();                  
                // 2 address seeds - so toggle between them
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    item.Address = _dbContext.Addresses.Single(s => s.Postcode == "one address");                   
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Address = _dbContext.Addresses.Single(s => s.Postcode == "second address");
                }

                _dbContext.Attach(item.Address);                    
                _dbContext.Courses.Add(item);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();                   

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was caused by the relationship definition

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // add the relationship       
  modelBuilder.Entity<Employer>().HasOne(u => u.Address).WithOne();      
}
```

This explanation by *ajcvickers* on GitHub clarifies it

> There is a one to one relationship between Address and Employee. That means that each Address can only be associated with a single Employee. Each iteration through the loop you assign the Address to a new Employee, which causes it to be unassigned from the previous Employee. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to model, but you may want a one to many relationship so that many employees can share the same address. If so, change your relationship mapping to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employer>().HasOne(u => u.Address).WithMany();
```